# Can this be atomically executed?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, atomic, interrupt

I would like to know whether it is possible to ensure `line` is atomically executed, given that it could be executed by both the ISR and Main context. I'm working on an **ARM9** (LPC313x) and using **RealView 4** (armcc).

```
foo() { 
  ..
  stack_var = ++volatile_var; // line
  ..
}
```

I'm looking for any routine like `_atomic_` for C166, direct assembly code, etc. I would prefer not to have to disable the interrupts.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a quick look, the C166 `_atomic_` macro seems to utilize an instruction that effectively masks interrupts for the duration of a specified number of instructions.
There is nothing directly corresponding to that in the ARM architecture.

You could of course use the swp instruction (or __swp intrinsic in the RealView toolchain) to implement a lock around the critical section. ldrex/strex mentioned in another answer do not exist in ARM architecture version 5, which includes the ARM9 processors.
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/CJAHDCHB.html and http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Chdbbbai.html respectively.

A simplistic lock implementation around this (using the RealView toolchain) would be:

```
{
    /* Loop until lock acquired */
    while (__swp(LOCKED, &lockvar) == LOCKED);
    ..
    /* Critical section */
    ..
    lockvar = UNLOCKED;
}
```

However, this *will* lead to deadlock in the ISR context when the Main thread is holding the lock.

I think masking interrupts around the operation is likely to be the least hairy solution, although if your Main context is executing in User mode it will require a system call to implement.

Comment: You can mix `swpb` with `swp` on older ARMs for multiple/single patterns.  Ie, **multiple flag setters** and **single flag clearer**.  Up to four `bytes` or **states** are available.

Answer (score 8):

No, I don't think that you ever can expect `++volatile_var` to be atomic, even if you don't have the assignment. Use a proper atomic primitive for that. If your compiler doesn't provide such an extension you easily find short inline assembler for that on the web. The assembler instructions are call `ldrex` and `strex` for atomic exchange on arm, I think.

**Edit:** it seems that the specific processor type that is asked for in the question does not implement these instructions.

**Edit:** The following should work with gcc, for another compiler one probably has to adapt the `__asm__` parts.

```
inline
size_t arm_ldrex(size_t volatile*ptr) {
  size_t ret;
  __asm__ volatile ("ldrex %0,[%1]\t@ load exclusive\n"
                    : "=&r" (ret)
                    : "r" (ptr)
                    : "cc", "memory"
                    );
  return ret;
}

inline
_Bool arm_strex(size_t volatile*ptr, size_t val) {
  size_t error;
  __asm__ volatile ("strex %0,%1,[%2]\t@ store exclusive\n"
                    : "=&r" (error)
                    : "r" (val), "r" (ptr)
                    : "cc", "memory"
                    );
  return !error;
}

inline
size_t atomic_add_fetch(size_t volatile *object, size_t operand) {
  for (;;) {
    size_t oldval = arm_ldrex(object);
    size_t newval = oldval + operand;
    if (arm_strex(object, newval)) return newval;
  }
}
```

Comment: It be helpful if someone can throw some light, but wouldn't the following be considered atomic ?

ADD r0, r0, #1           How can a ldrex/strex be used for incrementing a value ? I am surely missing something.

Comment: @Jens, I am bit new to this. Could you please point me to some resource/documentation that gives more details about the code   __asm__ volatile ("ldrex %0,[%1]\t@ load exclusive\n"
                    : "=&r" (ret)
                    : "r" (ptr)
                    : "cc", "memory"
                    );
I am not very clear about the what the stuff inside means.

Comment: @TheLoneJoker this is so-called "inline assembly", assembler instructions that are inserted in place, searching for that term should find you some more information. The variant I am using here is for gcc, others probably also support such extensions but which might look different in their implementation.

Comment: @Jens, Thank you. To help me get started, as an example could you please expand on what the following means ?  `ldrex %0,[%1]\t@ load exclusive\n"
                    : "=&r" (ret)
                    : "r" (ptr)
                    : "cc", "memory"
`,  I don't understand what is **cc** and **&r**

Comment: @TheLoneJoker, have a look here http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Comment: Another good article on GCC inline assembly is: http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html - GCC's inline assembly is complicated enough that enough that I'd often choose coding a function in a separate assembly source file instead of trying to convince myself that I've got the output/input/clobber specs for the inline assembly correct. Not to mention that it approaches being a write-only language - I cringe at the prospect of trying to decipher GCC inline assembly.

Comment: @Jens, This thread has been interesting indeed. I ended up doing some more reading and came upon this link:

Comment: Note that `lrdex` and `strex` require ARM architecture 6 or later, and don't exist on the ARM9.